# Is there a way to loop over multiple data-frames to drop the same columns?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have different data frames in `R` for which I would like to drop the same four columns, iterating the process for all of them throughout a loop.

When I use the subset and select on a single data frame, the line of code works fine. Yet, I always got some kind of error once I try some kind of iteration. Below, few attempts I made

Let's say I have two data frame `A` and `B`for which I want to drop the columns `sex`, `age`, `citizen` and `unit`.

Fine when I use subset and select on a single data frame:

```
A=subset(A, select = -c(sex,age,citizen,unit))
```

Then I tried to create a list of the two data frame and use a for loop as follow:

```
df.list <- list(A, B)

for(i in 1:2) {

  df.list<- subset(i, select = -c(sex,age,citizen,unit))

}
```

but I get the Error message:

> Error in subset.default: argument "subset" is missing, with no default

Comment: Trying '''lapply(df.list, function(x) subset(x, select = -c(sex,age,citizen,unit)))''' I see it show the right results, but it does not overwrite the existing data frames. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it because I don't have access right now to check it, but shouldn't it be like something like this:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
    df.list <- subset(df.list[i], select = ...)
}
```

Because you don't want to call the subset with first parameter = 1 but with the first parameter = the i-th element in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get the same error message (argument subset missing). When I view the list of the two data frames, I see that this both are marked as a list (under type column) and as a tibble with X rows and Y columns (under value column). Might this be the cause of the issue?